# Understanding aws ec2 default routes in

Tags: routing, route

After launching a new EC2 instance on AWS, I get the following routes. The LAN subnet is 10.0.0.0/24.

```
$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

I understand the first line and the third line. Can someone explain the second line to me? Sounds like it should stop all traffic to other machines on the local network (but it doesn't).

Comment: check http://serverfault.com/questions/644656/how-does-linux-pick-which-network-interface-to-use/644659 for detailed interpretation of route output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0 say's that it doesn't need to go to a gateway to reach the network 10.0.0.0/24 since it is part of the same network, that is instance/server ip address is also in the same network range.